# Date format on client browser

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am getting a date from the server as a javascript string(GMT) or unix timestamp(GMT).
I can convert it to a javascript date object with 
`var date = new Date(string)` or `var date = new Date(string)`

This gives me the `date` variable with proper system time-zone's time.

Currently I am displaying this- `date.toLocaleString()`

Which gives me a nicely formatted date/time according to my system locale and time zone.
I am using this to automatically accomodate for DST if the client browser follows it.

Previously I was required to display this date only in EST, but when the US time started following EDT, I was told to display it in EST. I think this approach would simplify displaying the time/date acoording to user's system time setting.

Is there any disadvantage or possible bug accociated with this approach?
If yes, what would be the best way to display this date in the browser, so that it displays correctly according to the timezone(accomodating DST if any) in which the user(cient browser) is?

Comment: [`toLocaleString` returns a string value that is similar to the following form. The exact format depends on the platform, locale and user's settings.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Using_toLocaleString)

Comment: when you do new Date() in Javascript you get the current date in his currently set time format. in casa you are sending the date from server it might be in different time format may be with daylight saving as well.

Comment: @AurA As I mentioned, the server time I am receiving is in GMT (+00 offset)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the output may be different depending on the users settings. A more reliable and flexibe solution is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which is a great library.

```
moment("2013-04-04", "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMM Do YY"); //"Apr 4th 13"
```

Comment: In this case I just have to display the date. It is not, and will not be used for any other purpose. It would be ok if it is not consistent across browsers. I think it would be even better if it displays according to system locale or users specified preferences.